# 'append' a file is not working in Python when file is in ADLS Gen 2

Tags: python

I need to append a file which is present in ADLS Gen2 storage.
Command executed successfully without any error in by azure databricks notebook. But when look  into the file not lines appended.

```
n = "/dbfs/mnt/executions/l0-l1/1db3bba9-b901-424f-b72c-9e5a073c1eeg/summary.csv"
f = open(n,'a')
f.write("my appended lines")
```

Can any one help

Comment: just a note: make sure you close out the file. Good habit

Comment: Even better habit - use a contexthandler to autoclose file on leaving the contexthandlers indentation

Comment: Or you can just use `f.flush` if you do not want to close it.

Answer (score 2):

Use `with()` to close the file soon as you're done manipulating it:

> The `with` statement creates a context manager and it will automatically
> close the file handler for you when you are done with it

```
with open (filepath, 'a') as fileObj:
    fileObj.write('some text')
```